# Cassandra 1 to Cassandra 2

Tags: java, cassandra, version, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Cassandra 1 to Cassandra 2.. And to do that I upgraded Java (to Java 7) but whenever I execute : cassandra. Its launching like this :

```
INFO 17:32:41,413 Logging initialized INFO 17:32:41,437 Loading
settings from file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml INFO 17:32:41,642
Data files directories: [/var/lib/cassandra/data] INFO 17:32:41,643
Commit log directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog INFO 17:32:41,643
DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO 17:32:41,643 disk_failure_policy is stop INFO 17:32:41,643
commit_failure_policy is stop INFO 17:32:41,647 Global memtable
threshold is enabled at 986MB INFO 17:32:41,727 Not using
multi-threaded compaction INFO 17:32:41,869 JVM vendor/version:
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_55 WARN 17:32:41,869 OpenJDK is not
recommended. Please upgrade to the newest Oracle Java release INFO
17:32:41,869 Heap size: 4137680896/4137680896 INFO 17:32:41,870 Code
Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 657664(642K)
committed = 2555904(2496K) max = 50331648(49152K) INFO 17:32:41,870
Par Eden Space Heap memory: init = 335544320(327680K) used =
80545080(78657K) committed = 335544320(327680K) max =
335544320(327680K) INFO 17:32:41,870 Par Survivor Space Heap memory:
init = 41943040(40960K) used = 0(0K) committed = 41943040(40960K) max
= 41943040(40960K) INFO 17:32:41,870 CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 3760193536(3672064K) used = 0(0K) committed = 3760193536(3672064K) max
= 3760193536(3672064K) INFO 17:32:41,872 CMS Perm Gen Non-heap memory: init = 21757952(21248K) used = 14994304(14642K) committed =
21757952(21248K) max = 174063616(169984K) INFO 17:32:41,872 Classpath:
/etc/cassandra:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-15.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snaptree-0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-internal-only-0.3.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.0.8.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-2.0.8.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/stress.jar::/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar
INFO 17:32:41,873 JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled. INFO
17:32:41,884 Initializing key cache with capacity of 100 MBs. INFO
17:32:41,890 Scheduling key cache save to each 14400 seconds (going to
save all keys). INFO 17:32:41,890 Initializing row cache with capacity
of 0 MBs INFO 17:32:41,895 Scheduling row cache save to each 0 seconds
(going to save all keys). INFO 17:32:41,968 Initializing
system.schema_triggers INFO 17:32:41,985 Initializing
system.compaction_history INFO 17:32:41,988 Initializing
system.batchlog INFO 17:32:41,991 Initializing system.sstable_activity
INFO 17:32:41,994 Initializing system.peer_events INFO 17:32:41,997
Initializing system.compactions_in_progress INFO 17:32:42,000
Initializing system.hints ERROR 17:32:42,001 Exception encountered
during startup java.lang.RuntimeException: Incompatible SSTable found.
Current version jb is unable to read file:
/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-hf-2.
Please run upgradesstables. at
org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:415)
at
org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:392)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.initCf(Keyspace.java:309) at
org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<init>(Keyspace.java:266) at
org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:110) at
org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:88) at
org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:536)
at
org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:261)
at
org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:496)
at
org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:585)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Incompatible SSTable found. Current
version jb is unable to read file:
/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-hf-2.
Please run upgradesstables. at
org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:415)
at
org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:392)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.initCf(Keyspace.java:309) at
org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<init>(Keyspace.java:266) at
org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:110) at
org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:88) at
org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:536)
at
org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:261)
at
org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:496)
at
org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:585)
Exception encountered during startup: Incompatible SSTable found.
Current version jb is unable to read file:
/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-hf-2.
Please run upgradesstables.
```

When i try to execute : upgradesstables (nodetool upgradesstables -h 127.0.0.1 -u root ...) I got this :

```
Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7000': Connexion refusée
```

Anyone can help me please ?

Thanks.

Comment: the error messages say that you should use Oracle's JDK instead of the open JDK. And they also say that you should run upgrade sstables. Have you done that?

Comment: This is what I get when I execute java -version : java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: Yep, your log says the same thing.

Comment: But I am sure I installed Java Oracle , I think there must be a conflict of various version of Java on the server... How to correct it ?

Comment: Openjdk is first in your path, then.  Look at your PATH variable and gwt sun's before the openjdk.

Comment: I got : /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64//bin:/home/dodger/workspace/android/sdk/tools

Comment: update-alternatives --config java
Il existe 3 choix pour l'alternative java (qui fournit /usr/bin/java).

  Sélection   Chemin                                          Priorité  État
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1052      mode automatique
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1051      mode manuel
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1052      mode manuel
  3            /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java             1         mode manuel

Comment: You want the oracle jdk to be in the path before or instead of the openjdk. You'll need to know where you installed the oracle jdk, and set your path. I set mine in my .bashrc like this: `export JAVA_HOME=/root/bootstrap/jdk1.7/` followed by 
`export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Eventually, Cassandra was purged, and now cqlsh is running successfully ! Thank you very much for your answers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cassandra error has nothing to do with OpenJDK, although I do recommend using Oracle's.

You need to make sure you're on a valid upgrade path: http://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeC_c.html

You can't trivially upgrade from a Cassandra older than 1.2.9 to 2.0, and you can't upgrade from 1.x to 2.1 without first going to 2.0.7 or later.

Suggested upgrade path per [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeC_c.html): 1.x > 1.2.9 > 2.0.7 > 2.1.x

Answer (score 0):

Your `java -version` output shows your not using correct JDK. It should be something like below.

> Java version "1.8.0_65"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

For this tell the system that there's a new Java version available

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_version/bin/java" 1
```

Set the new JDK as the default using the following command:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You can refer the link https://devopsmanual.in/2018/03/07/how-to-upgrade-datastax-cassandra/ for more details.